# Implement Language Selector

Tags: umbraco, multilingual, umbraco5

I have a site with two languages, en-GB and fr-FR. my site structure is as follows

Home

---en

------subpages

---fr

------subpages

i want to implement a Language selector so that a user can also select on the page he wants this page in English or French, any ideas how to implement that. i am using Umbraco 5

Regards n Thanks,

Sher

Comment: i don't know it in umbraco 5 , Can you please check this link http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multi-lingual-sites-under-a-single-domain.  You can add a macro to select the language, on the change you can redirect the site according to the selected value.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem but may be i can do something in the same line, it is not changing on the same page it redirects to the home page, thats not acceptable,

Comment: just to know.. i think you have added content nodes separately for each language. So i think you can redirect to that particular content node according to the selected value..

Comment: the problem is that the names and url's of same nodes in different languages are different and i have made some generalized document types so looping through it will not work either,

Comment: k.. i mean like adding the dropdown only on the home page, while selecting the language dropdown, redirect to corresponding url from that onwards there is no option to select the language..

Comment: yes this can be a option, i m going with that for now, may  be i come up with something else in future, Thanks Mahesh :)

Comment: k... please let me know if you got a better option..

Comment: i did some research in my structure and i find a tedious way out, but it is not optimum solution, i go through all the nodes like we build dynamic navigation and find the current node in other language with help of its document type, as for the pages with same document types and are siblings to each other, i used their properties to identify them, for example i had location pages, and they were of same document type but they had a property locationId, so i matched the locationId, if the location page is my current page, as i said it is not optimum but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks the best way to do it is to add to your document type a property (possibly dropdownlist data type), which will hold a special keyword for each document. For Instance:
create a doc type with property "keyword", that will be a master doctype for the rest of your document and when you create a new document, set the keyword to be whatever you want. Then you can search for the wanted page and navigate according to the keyword.